# Why variables initialized in functions can be accessed globally?

Tags: javascript, scope, hoisting

When one initialises a variable inside within a function's scope, presumably nothing can access that variable except for the function itself.

Why is it that sometimes variable initialisation in a function can be accessed globally ?

Below is some code:

```
function sayHello() {
  a = 'hello';
  console.log(a);
 }
}
```

actually becomes like this after hoisting:

```
function sayHello() {
  var a; // undefined
  a = 'hello';
  console.log(a);
 }
}

sayHello() // outputs 'hello'
console.log(a) // Reference error: a is not defined.
```

That is all good until this happens:

```
function sayGoodbye() {
  var b = 'Goodbye';
}
```

actually becomes this after hoisting

```
function sayGoodbye() {
  var b;
  b = 'Goodbye'
}

sayGoodbye() // undefined
console.log(b) // outputs 'Goodbye'
```

Why is it that after invoking sayGoodbye, the variable b becomes accessible globally or outside the function's scope whereas for sayHello, there is a reference error ?

Does console.log have anything to do with changing the scope ?

Comment: If you use a variable without defining it will be added to the global scope (it will throw an error if you are in strict mode)

Comment: ```function sayHello() {
  var a; // undefined
  a = 'hello';
  console.log(a);
 }
}```
Is invalid code: you have an extra `}`. Does this extra `}` "belongs" to a function that is not present in your snippet ?

Comment: read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: `function sayGoodbye() {
  var b;
  b = 'Goodbye'
}
` is not how hoisting works when you do not use `var` to declare your variables

Answer (score 1):

If you assign variable without declaring it becomes a global variable if you are not using strict mode.

```
function sayGoodbye() {
  b = 'Goodbye';
}
```

it becomes

```
var b;
function sayGoodbye() {
    b = 'Goodbye';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view of hoisting is not correct. When you **do not declare** a variable with `var`, it becomes a global variable when it is **encountered**. There is no hoisting of the variable. So if you never call `test`, the variable will not be defined in global scope.

```js
function test() {
  try {
    console.log("inside try", foo);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("nope inside try: ", e.message);
  }
  console.log("test before", typeof foo)
  foo = "bar";
  console.log("test after", typeof foo)
}

console.log('outside before called: ', typeof foo);
console.log('does not exist example: ', typeof bar);
try {
  console.log("outside try", foo);
} catch (e) {
  console.log("nope outside try: ", e.message);
}
test();
console.log('outside after called: ', typeof foo);
```

Now if you did use var to declare the variable, then it would be hoisted if you tried to use it before it was declared.

```js
function test() {
  // var foo; <-- it is hoisted to here
  try {
    console.log("inside try", foo);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("nope inside try: ", e.message);
  }
  console.log("test before", typeof foo)
  var foo = "bar";  // line here acts like foo="bar" since declared at top with hoisting.
  console.log("test after", typeof foo)
}

console.log('outside before called: ', typeof foo);
console.log('does not exist example: ', typeof bar);
try {
  console.log("outside try", foo);
} catch (e) {
  console.log("nope outside try: ", e.message);
}
test();
console.log('outside after called: ', typeof foo);
```